# Upload de arquivos em pastas separadas no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, upload, sistema-de-arquivos

Bom dia, primeiramente desculpem a minha noobisse mas ainda estou aprendendo kkk

Estou criando um sistema (Estou utilizando HTML,CSS,Javascript,PHP e o Banco MYSQL), onde terão vários usuários cadastrados e cada usuário poderá fazer o upload de arquivos em pdf.

A minha dúvida é qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Salvando eles no banco de dados MYSQL ou então salvando eles em uma pasta no servidor?

A minha ideia inicial era salvar em pasta no servidor, e que ao enviar o arquivo fosse criada uma pasta com o nome ou identificação do usuário e os arquivos ficassem salvos lá, pra ser mais fácil de identificar, porém, eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? me dar uma alguma dica?
Obrigado!!

Encontrei o seguinte código, é bem simples, teria um jeito melhor de fazer isso ou posso usar esse mesmo? segue abaixo o código:

```
session_start();

$message = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['uploadBtn']) && $_POST['uploadBtn'] == 'Upload')
{
  if (isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
  {
    // get details of the uploaded file
    $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'];
    $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));

    // sanitize file-name
    $newFileName = md5(date("m.d.y") . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;

    // check if file has one of the following extensions
    $allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'txt', 'xls', 'doc');

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions))
    {
      // directory in which the uploaded file will be moved
      $uploadFileDir = './uploaded_files/';
      $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $newFileName;

      if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)) 
      {
        $message ='File is successfully uploaded.';
      }
      else 
      {
        $message = 'There was some error moving the file to upload directory. Please make sure the upload directory is writable by web server.';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $message = 'Upload failed. Allowed file types: ' . implode(',', $allowedfileExtensions);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $message = 'There is some error in the file upload. Please check the following error.<br>';
    $message .= 'Error:' . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'];
  }
}
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
header("Location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, meu caro. Respondendo a sua dúvida:

**A minha dúvida é qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Salvando eles no banco de dados MYSQL ou então salvando eles em uma pasta no servidor?**

No meu ver os dois. Eu criaria uma tabela no banco, com o nome documentos, com alguns colunas mais ou menos assim `(doc_id, doc_nome, doc_tipo, user_id)` e relacionaria com a tabela usuários pelo `user_id`. Sobre as pastas eu já cometi esse erro de criar as pasta para cada usuário, da muito trabalho fazer a manutenção disso, a solução foi renomear o arquivo no upload com um padrão, onde era fácil identificar de quem ele era.

A formação do nome era a `data do dia + valor aleatório + user_id`, ficaria mais ou menos assim `20200922-KASO78445589554-11.pdf`, e salva tudo em uma pasta. Você pode melhorar essa nomenclatura usando funções de criptografia.

Comment: Entendi, então eu salvaria todos os arquivos pdf na mesma pasta com nome criptografado e salvaria no banco o nome dele, o nome criptografado, tipo, caminho... eu encontrei o seguinte um código aqui, vou postar ele ai em cima. acho que atende ao que vc disse

Comment: Exato, o código que você achou é bom eu só melhoraria essa linha `$newFileName = md5(date("m.d.y") . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;`, para melhorar a formação do nome, da forma que está vai gerar um hash baseado no valor data e no nome original do arquivo. Esse hash é bem grande e não te indica de qual usuário vem.